# How to do om namah shivaya pranayama(shiv panchakshari pranayam)

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, pranayama

I have read in shiv mahapuran that in form of pranayam,shiv Panchakshari is 100 times more beneficial. Do somebody know how to do it?